# Can't figure out why my seed file is creating rows with no data

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, model, seed

I’m using Rails 4.2.3 with a PostGre database.  I have this file that gets run as part of my “rake db:seed” command

```
Country.delete_all
Country.connection.execute("ALTER SEQUENCE countries_id_seq RESTART WITH 1")
Country.create(:id=>1,:iso=>"AD",:name=>"Andorra")
Country.create(:id=>2,:iso=>"AE",:name=>"United Arab Emirates")
Country.create(:id=>3,:iso=>"AF",:name=>"Afghanistan")
Country.create(:id=>4,:iso=>"AG",:name=>"Antigua and Barbuda")
Country.create(:id=>5,:iso=>"AI",:name=>"Anguilla")
Country.create(:id=>6,:iso=>"AL",:name=>"Albania")
…
```

Here is that table described …

```
\d countries;
                              Table "public.countries"
 Column |       Type        |                       Modifiers                        
--------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------
 id     | integer           | not null default nextval('countries_id_seq'::regclass)
 iso    | character varying | 
 name   | character varying | 
Indexes:
    "countries_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

However after running the above file, a bunch of rows get created but the iso and name fields are empty.  Here is my app/model/country.rb file

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :id, :iso, :name
end
```

Thanks for your help, - Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the `attr_accessor` line completely. ActiveRecord will define those methods for you based on the table columns. By having that line, you are essentially overriding the built-in ActiveRecord methods with versions that don't touch the database.